# XSLT - Pulling in data from a table that is out of the current context

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have searched under everything I can think of but falling short. I'm clearly new at xslt, so please be kind.

Firstly, I'm afraid I don't understand exactly how the `<template>` works. I've seen on others' example where there are multiple `<template>`'s declared. However, when I do that, the only thing that displays on the html output is the last one. Maybe someone can help me understand how this works. I've scrolled through dozens of references and have yet to understand it. References to specific learning materials and courses appreciated.

Secondly, here is the problem I'm working with. I *think* the issue stems from the fact that the `for-each` decares the context for the `value-of`, and what i'm trying to pull in in the third `value-of` is outside this context?

Here is a trimmed version of the xml i'm applying this stylesheet to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >  
  <component typeCode="COMP">
    <structuredBody classCode="DOCBODY" moodCode="EVN">
      <component typeCode="COMP" contextConductionInd="true">
        <section>
          <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5" />
          <code code="11450-43" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="PROBLEM LIST" />
          <title>Problems</title>
          <entry typeCode="DRIV" contextConductionInd="true">
            <act xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
               <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ" inversionInd="false">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                   <value xsi:type="CD" code="73211009" displayName="Chronic kidney disease, unspecified" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" codeSystemName="ICD-9-CM">
                    <originalText>
                      <reference value="#PROBKIND_0" />  
                    </originalText>
                  </value>
                </observation>
              </entryRelationship>
            </act>
          </entry>
          <entry typeCode="DRIV" contextConductionInd="true">
            <act xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
              <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ" inversionInd="false">
                <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                  <value xsi:type="CD" code="196001008" displayName="Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease with acute lower respiratory infection" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" codeSystemName="SNOMED CT">
                    <originalText>
                      <reference value="#PROBKIND_1" />
                    </originalText>
                  </value>
                 </observation>
              </entryRelationship>
            </act>
          </entry>
         </section>
      </component>
    </structuredBody>
  </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Here is what I have in the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:lookup="lookup" >  
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="problemEntries" select="if (count(//cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5.1']) > 0) then
                                                //cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5.1'] else
                                                //cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5']"/>


    <lookup:oids>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.1' oidName='LOINC'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.103' oidName='ICD9CM'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.104' oidName='ICD9CM'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.12' oidName='CPT'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.4' oidName='ICD10PCS'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88' oidName='RXNORM'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.90' oidName='ICD10CM'/>
        <row oid='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' oidName='SNOMEDCT'/>
    </lookup:oids>



    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <b>TEST Canonical Codes:</b>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>OID</th>
                        <th>System Name</th>
                        <th>Canonical System Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-entries($problemEntries/cda:entry/cda:act/cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:value)">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeSystem" /> <!-- to return the unique codeSystem (oid) values in the xml being evaluated -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeSystemName" /> <!-- to return the unique codeSystemName values the document has for that oid (oidName) -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="//document('')/lookup:oids/row[@oid = @codeSystem]/@oidName" /> <!-- to look up the unique code (oid) from above and lookup what the conanical name is (oidName) -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>             
    </template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've put comments next to each of the `value-of` to specify what i'm trying to do. Basically, here's what I'm looking to do:

- Get a unique list of all the codeSystem / codeSystemName combinations from all entries
- for each of the unique codeSystem values, do a lookup in the table to get the proper oidName and display in the respective row.

Here's my expected output, in an HTML table:
[HTML output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wl3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:lookup="lookup" >  
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="problemEntries" select="if (count(//cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5.1']) > 0) then
                                                //cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5.1'] else
                                                //cda:component/cda:section[cda:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.5']"/>


    <xsl:variable name="OIDs">
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" oidName="LOINC"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.103" oidName="ICD9CM"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.104" oidName="ICD9CM"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.12" oidName="CPT"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.4" oidName="ICD10PCS"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.88" oidName="RXNORM"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.90" oidName="ICD10CM"/>
            <row oid="2.16.840.1.113883.6.96" oidName="SNOMEDCT"/>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <b>TEST Canonical Codes:</b>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>OID</th>
                        <th>System Name</th>
                        <th>Canonical System Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$problemEntries/cda:entry/cda:act/cda:entryRelationship/cda:observation/cda:value">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeSystem" /> <!-- to return the unique codeSystem (oid) values in the xml being evaluated -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@codeSystemName" /> <!-- to return the unique codeSystemName values the document has for that oid (oidName) -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$OIDs//row[@oid = current()/@codeSystem]/@oidName" /> <!-- to look up the unique code (oid) from above and lookup what the conanical name is (oidName) -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>             
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1xZ

Comment: ahh, @Rupesh_Kr - Thank you - that works perfectly for adding the third column. Is there a way to limit the list to just distinct combinations?